# Count Dynamic Values In CodeIgniter Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

This is my JS code:

```
$('#type').on('change', function() {
    var id = $("#type").val();
    user_id = $("#user").val();
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url('types/getamount')?>",
        data: {
            user_id: user_id,
            id: id
        },
        beforeSend: function() {}
    }).done(function(data) {
        var jsonSectionsData = JSON.parse(data);
        var jj = 1;
        $.each(jsonSectionsData, function (key, value) {
            $('#due').val(value.due);
            $('#paid').val(value.paid);
            jj++;
        });
    });
});
```

When I change type I want to display all sum of amount but I am getting only the last inserted amount. Can any one tell me how to use `each()` for this concept?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We would need to see the format of the response you put in to `data` to help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

Alias a variable to hold reference to the value outside of the loop, and then work with that. After the loop, update the DOM.

```
var due = 0,
    paid = 0,
    jj = 1;

$.each(jsonSectionsData, function (key, value) {
    due = parseFloat( (due+value.due), 10);
    paid = parseFloat( (paid+value.paid), 10);
    jj++;
});
$('#due').val(due);
$("#paid').val(paid);
```

Something like this most likely.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Ohgodwhy, But I am get all paid values in a textbox instead of sum of paid amount

Comment: Can I see the format of your values so I can give you something that will add and format correctly for you.